# Delete a specific character in a list in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list that has a couple of dicts inside and they are all separated with a comma ",". What is happening is that when i create this list i am adding , inside a for loop, a comma after every dict to separate them but it is also adding a last comma after the last dictionary. Something like:

```
"guests": [{
    "age": "18",
    "birthDate": null,
    "emailAddress": null,...
    ....
    "name": {
    "prefix": "Mr.",
    "firstName": "James",
    "middleName": "",
    "lastName": "Jones",
    "suffix": ""
    }
},----------------------------->This comma
]
```

I think that last comma is creating some issues when trying to make a post request to the web service. So, How can i delete just that last comma inside the list?

Thanks

**Edit**

The creation of the list is happening inside a for loop. Something like:

```
participants_body = ''

for guest in guests_info:

        post_body = '{"profile": {"name": {"title": "' + guest["title"] + '","firstName": "' \
                           + guest["first_name"] + '","lastName": "' + guest["last_name"] \
                           + '"},"age": 18},"preferences": {"avatarIdentifier": "15655408","favoriteCharacterIdentifier":' \
                             ' "15655408"},"friendsAndFamily": {"groupClassification": {"name": "TRAVELLING_PARTY"},' \
                             '"accessClassification": {"name": "PLAN_VIEW_SHARED"}}}'

        response = requests.post(url, data=post_body, headers=headers)

        json_response = response.json()

       participants_body = '{"age": "' + str(json_response["profile"]["age"]) + '","birthDate": null,"emailAddress": null,' \
                            '"phone": null,"primary": false,"swid": null,"guid": "' + guid + '","gender": null,"type": null,' \
                            '"participantId": "' + p_id + '","profileLink": "https://env5.nge.api.go.com' + profileLink + '", ' \
                            '"infantSittingWithAdult": false,"avatar": null,"itemsAssigned": ' \
                            '["' + item_id + '"],"address": null,"phoneNumber": null,"dataType": "basic",' \
                            '"isRoomAssigned": true,"isVacationOfferAssigned": true,"ageGroup": "","name": {' \
                            '"prefix": "' + json_response["profile"]["name"]["title"] + '","firstName": "' \
                            + json_response["profile"]["name"]["firstName"] + '","middleName": "","lastName": "' \
                            +

                           json_response["profile"]["name"]["lastName"] + '","suffix": ""}},'------------> HERE IS THE COMA

        post_body_participants += participants_body
```

So, that´s why i´m getting the coma. I just need to delete it after the for loop

**EDIT**

I´m creating a Post message and i´m getting this error:

```
{u'errors': [{u'message': u'org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.disney.wdpro.service.booking.webservice.resource.ParticipantWithAssignmentResourceCollection] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method'}]}
```

I read a couple of SO questions and they mentioned that maybe this is happening because an error with the json format.

Also i can see how the body of the post is created in other messages in the logs and that last comma is not there, so maybe that´s what´s happening

Comment: Is this an actual list of dictionaries, or a string? If you are talking about building such a string, try `",".join(list_of_dict_strings)`. Also, have you tried the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module, particularly `json.dumps`?

Comment: how is this being built?  why do you think the comma is a problem in the post?  how are you posting the data?

Comment: It is strange because python automatically deletes this comma for you

Comment: Please save yourself pain and do not build json strings by hand. Build the Python objects and then use json.dumps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're creating this as a string. You'll be happier to create the dicts as dicts. The code is much more readable, which will help you when you have to change it later. Besides that, it will eliminate little typo bugs like you're experiencing.

```
post_body = {
    'profile': {
        'name': {
            'title': guest['title'],
            'firstName': guest['first_name'],
            'lastName': guest['last_name'] },
        'age': 18 },
    'preferences': {
        'avatarIdentifier': 15655408,
        'favoriteCharacterIdentifier': 15655408 },
    'friendsAndFamily': {
        'groupClassification': {
            'name': 'TRAVELLING_PARTY' },
        'accessClassification': {
            'name': 'PLAN_VIEW_SHARED' }
    }
}
```

It's easy to turn that dict into a JSON string:

```
import json
post_body = json.dumps(post_body)
```

You can do the same thing with creating a list from the `participants_body` response. Just create the one dict as above, and append it with `post_body_participants.append(participants_body)`. Again, you can access that list in the form of a JSON string with `json.dumps(post_body_participants)`.

Comment: I´m creating it as a list because that´s what the web service is specting

Comment: It will make your life much, much easier to create it as a dict or a list, and then to convert it into a string.

Comment: @user3799942 - I typed up a similar answer, but Greg beat me, and his was better.  I suggest you take his advice.

Answer (score 1):

You will save yourself a great deal of pain if you use the built in json encoders/decoders to build your json strings. Building them by hand is error prone. Why not stand on the shoulders of giants?

```
import requests
import json

participants =[]

for guest in guests_info:
    #Build Python objects and not json strings
    #Convert it all to json later
    post_body = {
        'profile': {
            'name': {
                'title': guest['title'],
                'firstName': guest['first_name'],
                'lastName': guest['last_name'] },
            'age': 18 },
        'preferences': {
            'avatarIdentifier': 15655408,
            'favoriteCharacterIdentifier': 15655408 },
        'friendsAndFamily': {
            'groupClassification': {
                'name': 'TRAVELLING_PARTY' },
            'accessClassification': {
                'name': 'PLAN_VIEW_SHARED' }
        }
    }

    #The requests module has json encoding/decoding built in
    response = requests.post(url, json=post_body, headers=headers)  
    #Or you could use Python's built in json module
    #response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(post_body), headers=headers)  

    json_response = response.json() #This decodes the json string in the response to a Python object


    participant = {
        "age": json_response["profile"]["age"],
        "birthDate": None,
        "emailAddress": None,
        "phone": None,
        "primary": False,
        "swid": None,
        "guid": guid,
        "gender": None,
        "type": None,
        "participantId": p_id,
        "profileLink": "https://env5.nge.api.go.com" + profileLink + ,
        "infantSittingWithAdult": False,
        "avatar": None,
        "itemsAssigned": [item_id],
        "address": None,
        "phoneNumber": None,
        "dataType": "basic",
        "isRoomAssigned": True,
        "isVacationOfferAssigned": True,
        "ageGroup": "",
        "name": {
            "prefix": json_response["profile"]["name"]["title"],
            "firstName": json_response["profile"]["name"]["firstName"],
            "middleName": "",
            "lastName": json_response["profile"]["name"]["lastName"],
            "suffix": ""}
        }
    }

    participants.append(participant)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but `null`, `true` and `false` are not valid Python keywords. I think those should be `None`, `True` and `False`. `json.dumps` will convert those accordingly.